# Losing date index from dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a resampled (hourly) pandas dataframe, indexed by daterun, into tuples. Here is the dataframe:

```
ratetype                        p_rate     v_rate  
daterun                                        
2013-10-24 13:00:00              1          0  
2013-10-24 14:00:00              3          0  
2013-10-24 15:00:00              5          0  
2013-10-24 16:00:00              7          1   

In [67]: type(df_p)
Out[67]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

I am converting to tuples using:

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df_p.values]
```

My problem is that the date isn't included in the tuples array:

```
In [69]: tuples
Out[69]: 
[(1, 0),
(3, 0),
(5, 0),
(7, 1)]
```

How can I include the date column so that I end up with:

```
In [69]: tuples
Out[69]: 
[(2013-10-24 13:00:00, 1, 0),
 (2013-10-24 13:00:00, 3, 0),
 (2013-10-24 13:00:00, 5, 0),
 (2013-10-24 13:00:00, 7, 1)]
```

I don't mind if the datetime format is different.

Answer (score 1):

`values` doesn't include the index. You want [dataframe.itertuples()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#itertuples).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.to_records().tolist()
```